# do while with cursor only returning 3 values from an array

Tags: java, android

I want to return the name and all the numbers for a single contact. for example if a contact has 4 numbers i want to return it as phone1, phone2,etc... . I have a code that opens contact list and and return only one contact. I Changed it to this but it either returns three contacts or none at all.

```
     String phoneNum;

      int dataIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.DATA1);

      int mimeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Entity.MIMETYPE);

      cursor.moveToFirst();

       int i = 0;

       do {
           i++;
           phoneNum = "phone" + i ;
           returnKeys.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,"name");
           returnKeys.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, phoneNum);
           returnKeys.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, "email");

           mime = cursor.getString(mimeIdx);

           if(returnKeys.containsKey(mime)) {
                contactData.putString((String) 
                returnKeys.get(mime)
                cursor.getString(dataIdx));

                cursor.moveToNext();
                foundData = true;
          }
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());

      cursor.close();
      if(foundData) {
           mContactsPromise.resolve(contactData);
           return;
      } else {
          mContactsPromise.reject(E_CONTACT_NO_DATA, "No data found for contact");
          return;
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       mContactsPromise.reject(E_CONTACT_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
       return;
   }
```

Comment: Please fix code indentation so it no longer starts at column 475 which is PITA when reading on the phone.

Comment: I edited the code is it better now?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is, but it still indented too much. Either add 4 spaces on each code line or use ``` (three backticks) to mark begin and end of your code block (and then you do not need anything else, esp. you don't need both).

Comment: use  `rawQuery` method. for example like this `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" select * from Tablo where name= ? ", new String[]{name}`